Calculating Standard Error (SE) of a Nonlinear Function Using SE of Its Parameters
I'm working with a nonlinear function, specifically a beta weighting scheme, which generates weights that can vary in shape (e.g., decaying, hump-shaped, U-shaped). I have estimates for the parameters (ω1 and ω2) of this function along with their respective standard errors (SE(ω1) and SE(ω2)).
To clarify, this function returns the lag coefficients for a given lag horizon (K). The lag coefficients sum up to 1, and I determine the lag value as the point K where the cumulative sum of these coefficients reaches 95% of the total.
Could someone please guide me on how to calculate the standard error of this function, particularly for the determined lag value, using the standard errors of its parameters? I understand that this typically involves the delta method, but I'm unsure about the exact steps and formula application in this context.
Thank you in advance for your help!
